# Excel vba - changing number of rows in range in series and axis label

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range, row

I'm new with vba and I need some assistance with something.
For a lot of charts I have a huge range and then I have the need to hide unused ranges and that's especially confusing when I transfer charts to ppt.
What I need is a macro to change the rows' ranges...the columns stay the same. Something like:

```
Sub test()

Dim YearB As Integer
Dim YearE As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim srs As Series

YearB = InputBox("Beggining Year")

YearE = InputBox("Ending Year")


'define the rows corresponding to the year
i = YearI - 1994

j = YearF - 1994


Set sht = ActiveSheet
    With sht
        For Each cht In .ChartObjects
            For Each srs In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
                    'code to change rows in range and axis



            Next srs
        Next cht
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone help me, please??!

Comment: Have you done any research on this?  MSDN/Google/Debugged the `srs` object?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav As I said I'm new in vba and I researched and found no solution for this problem...somethings I wrote may not be correct

Comment: as suggested by @Nathan_Sav attempting to manipulate  series and axis object with VBA require clear understanding of series (may be multiple) and Axis objects. If your data and chart placements not overlap why not try simple filter on the date,.chart will automatically adjust to visible data.

Comment: You sure?  Googling `change series data source vba` gives lots of examples, the 1st being a) on this site and b) what you want :o)  Being new to VBA doesn't really cut it on this site. :o(

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: to be fair to OP, your search results on Google are based on few different factors so OP might not get the first answer from this site :). Saying that, this is not a new question. There will be answers for it on Google. You might not understand them.. being new to VBA. In which case it might be an idea to familiarise yourself with VBA

Comment: @AhmedAU the thing is that then a lot of info is filtered, because there are a lot of charts. Loading them into PPT causes a lot of Invisible Content which slows down a lot the file, for example.

Comment: Also, a quick look at your code, `Dim YearI, YearF As Integer`: this statement will only declare `YearF` as integer. `Yearl` will be declared as a `Variant`. If you want to declare both as `Integer`, try something like: `Dim %Yearl, %YearF`

Comment: How can I load up columns of a range and maintain them, and change the rows?? That's what it's missing.

Comment: Any links to help with this?

Comment: @Zac Thank you.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I know the basics, usually from research...for this particular case I didn't find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want to do, but if you want to automate the entire process of updating charts in powerpoint rather than transfering the new charts manually from Excel, you can actually update ranges of the existing charts directly powerpoint.Try something like below. VBA takes the range from the active sheet.

```
Dim PPTApp As Object
Dim PPTPres As Object
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPTApp.Visible = True

'This opens your powerpoint presentation
Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Open("file:///C:\Users\first.name\Desktop\pptest111.pptx")
PPTPres.Windows(1).Activate

'This sets the range for x-axis labels
PPTPres.Slides(2).Shapes("Diagram1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "Sheet2!$D$5:$D15"
'This sets the new range of values
PPTPres.Slides(2).Shapes("Diagram1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "Sheet2!$E$5:$E8"

PPTPres.Slides(2).Shapes("Diagram1").LinkFormat.Update
```